# extent report version 4 screenshot not generating

Tags: screenshot, selenium-extent-report

I simply do not understand why this error occurs. Unable to generate the extent report and capture screenshot. I have appended the Test, AfterMethod & AfterTest and screenshot method. I want to capture screenshots under a different folder.

The error message i am getting is as following.

> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod getReport([TestResult
>   name=checkTitle status=SUCCESS method=Google.checkTitle()[pri:0,
>   instance:Google@3224f60b] output={null}]) java.io.IOException: The
>   filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect hod.

Following is my selenium test code.

```
@Test
public void checkTitle() {
    test = extent.createTest("Title Check test");
    Actual_Title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(Actual_Title);
    Assert.assertEquals(Actual_Title, Expected_Tite);
    test.log(Status.PASS, "This Test is Passed!");
}

@AfterMethod
public void getReport(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        test.log(Status.FAIL,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),ExtentColor.RED));
        test.fail("TestFailed due to"+"  "+result.getThrowable().getMessage());
        String imagePath =Google.captureScreen(driver,result.getName());
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(imagePath);
    }
    else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        test.log(Status.SKIP,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),ExtentColor.AMBER));
        test.skip(result.getThrowable().getMessage());
    } else {
        test.log(Status.PASS,MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),ExtentColor.GREEN));
        String imagePath =Google.captureScreen(driver, result.getName());
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(imagePath);
    }

}

@AfterTest
public void endTest() {
    extent.flush();
    driver.quit();
}

public static String captureScreen(WebDriver driver,String screenshotname)throws IOException {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy,hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File src= ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ScreenShots/"+screenshotname+date+".png";
    File destination = new File(path);
    FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem.
For below code, I am getting exact same error as you mentioned.

```
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy,hh:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        String screenshotname = "MyScreenshot";
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test- 
        output/"+screenshotname+date+".png";
        logger.info("In failedTCTakeScreenshot:: ******path***** " + path);
```

Error in log

```
      [INFO ] 2020-07-28 23:09:52.281 [main] com.resources.BaseTest -In 
      failedTCTakeScreenshot:: ******path***** 
      E:\Automation\EclipseWorkspace\AutomationPrj/test-output/MyScreenshot07-28- 
      20,11:09:52.png

      [ERROR] 2020-07-28 23:09:52.285 [main] com.resources.BaseTest - 
      BaseTest::failedTCTakeScreenshot::***In Catch Block *** java.io.IOException: The 
      filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Root cause Analysis:-

On analysis , I found that, you are storing your screenshot having name MM-dd-yy,hh:mm:ss date format in it. Windows does not accept any : or , in filename. You need to change your screenshotname so that it does not contains : , etc.

When I change DateFormat in my code  to MM-dd-yyyy , I could successfully copy screenshot and no error thrown.

```
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());
        String screenshotname = "MyScreenshot";
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test- 
        output/"+screenshotname+date+".png";
        logger.info("In failedTCTakeScreenshot:: ******path***** " + path);
```

Log :-

```
      [INFO ] 2020-07-28 23:24:27.457 [main] com.resources.BaseTest - In 
      failedTCTakeScreenshot:: ******path***** 
      E:\Automation\EclipseWorkspace\AutomationPrj/test-output/MyScreenshot07-28- 
      2020.png

      [INFO ] 2020-07-28 23:24:27.463 [main] com.resources.BaseTest - In 
      failedTCTakeScreenshot:: ******path destination***** 
      E:\Automation\EclipseWorkspace\AutomationPrj\test-output\MyScreenshot07-28- 
      2020.png
```

So you just need to change Screenshotname so that it should not contains special characters like ; and ,

Comment: I will surely try. Thanks for the help.